# Manhwa where female lead unseals the male lead while being thrown off a cliff

Tags: story-identification, manga

Looking for a manhwa where the female lead was about to be killed by her family and they threw her off the cliff but she undid the seal of a overpowered male lead who was sealed there for hundred of years.